# Task Cancelation upon error before all tasks are finished

Tags: c#

So Im trying to cancel a task when an error state occurs and throw a taskcancelationsource.cancel(true) which in turn throws an exception.

Problem is that when the error occurs the cancellation doesnt get invoked until after all the tasks have finished. The IsInError.Value is set in a NotifyCollectionChanged event which gets fired when an error message is added to the messages collection.

I have to do the "await Task.WhenAll(tasks)" which is probably keeping everything running until they are all done and I can evaluate if there was an error.

```
return Task.Run(async () =>
{
    concreteModel.TotalStepCount.Value = 11;
    try
    {
        if (args.EventArgs.EtlOperationType == EtlOperationType.StandardVehicle)
        {
            concreteModel.CompletedStepCount.Value += 1;
        }
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => StandardVehicleConversionStorageProxy.ConvertData(container, importRawData), taskCancellationToken));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        if (concreteModel.IsInError.Value)
        {
             taskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel(true);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conversionOperation.IsInProgress.Value = false;
        if (subscription != null)
        {
            subscription.Dispose();
        }
    }
}, taskCancellationToken);
```

And the task cancellation error is handled in the calling procedure...

```
private async Task<bool> convertAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await ConversionOperations.Single(x => x.OperationType == EtlOperationType.StandardVehicle).ConvertAsync(Container, _cancellationSource, ImportRawData);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        // handle the throw task cancellation exception
        ex.Task.Dispose();
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        IsConverting.Value = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking for an error after calling `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`.  This won't happen until all tasks are complete.

Instead you should call `taskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel(true);` in an event handler while the tasks are still running.

You'll also need to pass `taskCancellationToken` to `StandardVehicleConversionStorageProxy.ConvertData` and check for token cancellation using `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` or `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ()` to handle the cancel request.

Comment: Sounds logical, Thanks! The taskCancellationToken can be passed to ConvertData which executes a ResponsibilityChain. I think Ill have to throw the task error in each of the steps where the IsInError is being set.